# Codeigniter. Where/How should I write the login method if it's on the footer

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

beginner question sorry: I have template that have header, navbar, content,  sidebar,  footer.
but my loginbox  is on the sidebar   and my view files 'footer.php' consist of sidebar and footer. (so my loginbox is on footer.php)
My controller, every method must import the header.php view, somemodule.php(content) view and footer.php view.

the problem is when I write the login method,  it does not have content view because loginbox is in footer already. no nescessary for somemodule.php(content)view. (my login form post data to controller login method)

this is my controller

```
 public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('header');

    /// login and validation  algorithm here////
    /// not have $this->load->view('some content') ///

    $this->load->view('footer');  ////my loginform is footer

}
 public function register()
{
   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('register_content');   // so this has a content
   //// algorithm and validation here /////
   $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

this is my form in the footer view

```
<?php echo form_open('member/login');?>  //post data to method login controller
                    <h2> Login </h2>
                    <ul id='login'>
                        <li>
                            Username:<br>
                            <input type='text' name='username'>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Password:<br>
                            <input type='password' name='password'>
                        </li>
                        <br>
                        <li>
                            <input type='submit' value='Log in'>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </form>
```

When the user input wrong password, I want the website to be on same page with error message  and  the "content view" still be the same.

Comment: you are going to need to explain this using code outline. Not at all clear what you are doing or what the specific problem is. see [mcve]

Comment: Also note that a form can be anywhere in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [flashdata](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata) from [session library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

For exemple, in your login controller :

```
public function login() {
    // Do your logic... Don't load any views or anything
    if ($error) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE);
    }

    // Load the user agent library
    $this->load->library('user_agent');

    // Load the url help
    $this->load->helper('url');

    // Then redirect to the previous page. You can add more security and check if the previous page is not empty and is from your website.
    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
}
```

Then in your header view :

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('login_error')): ?>
    <div class="error">Something went wrong ! Check your username / password.</div>
<?php endif;?>
```